# Suggestion to make tag "chi-square" a synonym of tag "chi-squared"?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

The newly created tag [chi-square](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chi-square) seems to be a synonym of tag [chi-squared](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chi-squared).

Comment: Thanks for bringing our attention to this duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These two tags have been merged. Master tag is [chi-squared](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chi-squared), and [chi-square](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chi-square) is now a synonym.

Comment: Thanks for your help!